# Show 2 pages at 2 different times at same URL in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a registration form in Wordpress which is built on Formidable Forms plugin like this

```
mysite.com/registration/
```

After registration deadline is over (which I will save dates in database), the same registration page will show a message "Registration is Over"
Is this something any available plugin can do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write a conditional on your registration page template:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$deadline = new DateTime('2016-04-28 1:00:00');

if ( $now > $deadline ) {
    // Registration is over!
} else {
    // show the registration form
}
```

Comment: I was exactly going to implement same thing but thanks for your help :)